# How to use JSOM to retrieve list of people who directly reports to a given manger

Tags: jsom, people-search

I am trying to write a JSOM to return list of people who report to a given person (manager) based on the Org Chart structure in SharePoint.

I know that context is able to load things such as peers and extendedManager, but how to get the list people who reports to a given person?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out, ExtendedReports property shows the people who reports to.

There were actually wasn't enough person data for Org Browser webpart to work out all properties.